# Can cobalt support transparent background

Tags: cobalt

When body's background color is set as transparent as below, the actual background is displayed as purple in cobalt.

```
body {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Is there any way to make background to be real transparent? I wish to show other gfx or video layers under cobalt's graphics layer. Thanks!

Comment: Hi balancekeeper, my original answer I think was actually not complete, I've edited it now to something that should actually work.

Answer (score 0):

As an optimization, Cobalt does not clear its framebuffer each frame, however this can indeed cause a problem if you would like to use it as an overlay.

In cobalt/renderer/pipeline.cc, right after the line:

```
rasterizer::Rasterizer::Options rasterizer_options;
```

but before the line:

```
rasterizer_->Submit(results.animated, render_target, rasterizer_options);
```

If you add:

```
rasterizer_options.flags = rasterizer::Rasterizer::kSubmitFlags_Clear;
```

Cobalt will clear each frame to be fully transparent before rendering the contents.

We will look into adding a nicer way to express this desire in the future, but hopefully this helps for now.

Answer (score 0):

So comment out the following line from src/cobalt/renderer/backend/egl/graphics_context.cc:GraphicsContextEGL::SecurityClear()

```
GL_CALL(glClearColor(1.0f, 0.4f, 1.0f, 1.0f));
```

Comment: Hey Daniel, fyi I realized later that my original answer wouldn't actually solve this problem, and I just now updated it to something else that actually would solve this problem.

Comment: Got it. I will check your another answer.